# How to parameterize an injectable service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service as the core of a framework that will we be incorporated into many projects. It saves some data to local storage with a key that is currently static. I would like to make the key instead passed in as a parameter so it can be unique for every project. This is because when I'm testing from `localhost:4200` on any of these projects there is a conflict with that local storage field/key. What I have is:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

private static readonly STORAGE_ID = 'model-data';

     constructor(  ) {

    }

    someFunction() {
        localStorage.setItem(MyService.STORAGE_ID, JSON.stringify(this._model))
    }

}
```

How can I add a parameter to the constructor so it can still be instantiated through Angular 2 dependency injection?

Comment: It would be easier if you'd provide a concrete code example. Just add a constructor parameter and register some provider for it.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, "add a constructor parameter and register some provider for it." I'm not clear on what that means.

Comment: I guess it's at least as clear as your question ;-) For an abstract question an abstract answer :p

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, I updated my question with a concrete example.

Answer (score 5):

You could provide a constructor parameter for the key:

```ts
export const STORAGE_KEY = new InjectionToken<string>('storageKey');

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject(STORAGE_KEY) private storageKey: string) { }

  ...
}
```

Then in your `providers` you need to supply a value for it:

```ts
providers: [
  { provide: STORAGE_KEY, useValue: 'this-app-key' },
  MyService,
  ...
]
```

An example is given [in the DI documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#injection-token).

---

Alternatively, create a factory provider function:

```ts
export function createServiceFactory(storageKey: string) {
    return () => new MyService(storageKey);
}
```

and use that:

```ts
{ provide: MyService, useFactory: createServiceFactory('that-app-key') }
```

This way you don't need to `@Inject` the parameter.